# How to get date that comes after a date column in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-redshift

I have this table full of date columns of each status:

```
awb    manifest_date  out_branch_date  in_branch_date  ant_date    dlv_date      cc_date
ab123   2023-07-01      2023-07-02      2023-07-03    2023-07-04   2023-07-05    2023-07-04
ab124   2023-07-03      2023-07-03      2023-07-04    2023-07-05   2023-07-06    2023-07-08
ab125   2023-07-04      2023-07-09      2023-07-05    2023-07-06   2023-07-08    2023-07-09
ab127   2023-07-04      2023-07-05      2023-07-06    2023-07-07   2023-07-08    2023-07-05
```

I want to the next date and also the next status that comes after `ant_date` by looking all the date columns. What I have tried so far is using `case when`:

```
select awb,
       case when manifest_date > ant_date then 'manifest'
            when out_branch_date > ant_date then 'out branch'
            when in_branch_date > ant_date then 'in branch'
            when dlv_date > ant_date then 'dlv'
            when cc_date > ant_date then 'cc' else null end as status_after_ant,
       case when manifest_date > ant_date then manifest_date
            when out_branch_date > ant_date then out_branch_date
            when in_branch_date > ant_date then in_branch_date
            when dlv_date > ant_date then dlv_date
            when cc_date > ant_date then cc_date else null end as date_status_after_ant
from data
```

This query returns:

```
awb      status_after_ant     date_status_after_ant
ab123      dlv                  2023-07-05
ab124      cc                   2023-07-08
ab125      cc                   2023-07-09
ab127      dlv                  2023-07-08
```

Unfortunately the query gives the wrong results, the status for `ab124` and `ab125` supposed to be `dlv` instead of `cc`. It's because the `cc_date` is more than `ant_date`.

How should I fix my query if I want to the get the status that comes right after `ant_date` out of all the date columns. My table is on amazone redshift. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is due to the pivoted format of your data. It will be ever so much easier if the data is "unpivoted"

```
SELECT
  awb,
  status,
  status_date
FROM data
UNPIVOT (
  status FOR status_date IN (manifest_date, out_branch_date, in_branch_date, ant_date, dlv_date, cc_date)
)
```

Which will make the data look like this

```
  awb          status          status_date  
 -------- ------------------- -------------- 
  ab123     manifest_date       2023-07-01   
  ab123     out_branch_date     2023-07-02   
  ab123     in_branch_date      2023-07-03   
  ab123     ant_date            2023-07-04   
  ab123     dlv_date            2023-07-05   
  ab123     cc_date             2023-07-04   
  ab124     manifest_date       2023-07-03   
  ab124     out_branch_date     2023-07-03   
  ab124     in_branch_date      2023-07-04   
  ab124     ant_date            2023-07-05   
  ab124     dlv_date            2023-07-06   
  ab124     cc_date             2023-07-08
```

Now it is far easier to deduce the next status and associated date, because we can order the dates:

```
    SELECT
      awb,
      status,
      status_date,
      LEAD(status, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY awb ORDER BY status_date) AS next_status,
      LEAD(status_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY awb ORDER BY status_date) AS next_status_date
    FROM data
    UNPIVOT (
      status FOR status_date IN (manifest_date, out_branch_date, in_branch_date, ant_date, dlv_date, cc_date)
    )
    WHERE status = 'ant_date'


   awb       status      status_date     next_status     next_status_date  
 -------- ------------ --------------- --------------- ------------------- 
  ab123     ant_date     2023-07-04      dlv_date        2023-07-05        
  ab124     ant_date     2023-07-05      dlv_date        2023-07-06        
  ab127     ant_date     2023-07-06      cc_date         2023-07-07
```

---

If Redshift doesn't support UNPIVOT then it's a bit clumsier to do that bit e.g:

```
SELECT awb, 'manifest_date' as status, manifest_date as status_date FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT awb, 'out_branch_date' as status, out_branch_date as status_date FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT awb, 'in_branch_date' as status, in_branch_date as status_date FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT awb, 'ant_date' as status, ant_date as status_date FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT awb, 'dlv_date' as status, dlv_date as status_date FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT awb, 'cc_date' as status, cc_date as status_date FROM data
```

Comment: If you don't want to see "_date" in the output use substring e.g `SUBSTRING(status, 1, LENGTH(status) - 5) AS status`